# Does formatting efi partition on a Chromebook (with custom firmware) affects ChromeOS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, uefi, firmware, chrome-os

Recently I got a Chromebook ([board](https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices): SASUKE), I've been able to install a custom firmware following [these instructions](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript). Now I have a messy partition table (I used [chrx](https://chrx.org/)) and I installed a working Arch Linux on a partition, but to do that I played a lot with the EFI partition (but I never deleted things I did not created, indeed I can still access ChromesOS). I would like to polish my EFI by formatting it (like this: `mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/efi_system_partition`) because I configured GRUB in a 'dirty way', is it dangerous for ChromeOS? Can I still boot into it or does it get affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I formatted the efi and it did not affect ChromeOS